# How to compute hessian matrix for all parameters in a network in pytorch?

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, hessian

Suppose vector `\theta` is all the parameters in a neural network, I wonder how to compute hessian matrix for `\theta` in pytorch.

Suppose the network is as follows:

```
class Net(Module):
    def __init__(self, h, w):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.c1 = torch.nn.Conv2d(1, 32, 3, 1, 1)
        self.f2 = torch.nn.Linear(32 * h * w, 5)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.c1(x)
        x = x.view(x.size(0), -1)
        x = self.f2(x)
        return x
```

I know the second derivative can be calculated by calling `torch.autograd.grad()` twice, but the parameters in pytorch is organized by `net.parameters()`, and I don't know how to compute the hessian for all parameters.

I have tried to use `torch.autograd.functional.hessian()` in pytorch 1.5 as follows:

```
import torch
import numpy as np
from torch.nn import Module
import torch.nn.functional as F


class Net(Module):
    def __init__(self, h, w):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.c1 = torch.nn.Conv2d(1, 32, 3, 1, 1)
        self.f2 = torch.nn.Linear(32 * h * w, 5)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.c1(x)
        x = x.view(x.size(0), -1)
        x = self.f2(x)
        return x


def func_(a, b c, d):
    p = [a, b, c, d]
    x = torch.randn(size=[8, 1, 12, 12], dtype=torch.float32)
    y = torch.randint(0, 5, [8])
    x = F.conv2d(x, p[0], p[1], 1, 1)
    x = x.view(x.size(0), -1)
    x = F.linear(x, p[2], p[3])
    loss = F.cross_entropy(x, y)
    return loss


if __name__ == '__main__':
    net = Net(12, 12)

    h = torch.autograd.functional.hessian(func_, tuple([_ for _ in net.parameters()]))
    print(type(h), len(h))
```

`h` is a tuple, and the results are in strange shape. For example, the shape of `\frac{\delta Loss^2}{\delta c1.weight^2}` is `[32,1,3,3,32,1,3,3]`. It seems like I can combine them into a complete `H`, but I don't know which part it is in the whole Hessian Matrix and the corresponding order.

Comment: And in this way, I need to build a function just has the same function with class Net, which is too complex. Is there any simpler solution?

Comment: How is hessian matrix useful here? What task will it resolve? Just curious.

Comment: @JodhSingh some specific algorithms or analysis. For example, the importance of different weights for the training loss

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is one solution, I think it's a little too complex but could be instructive.

Considering about these points:

1. First, about `torch.autograd.functional.hessian()` the first argument must be a function, and the second argument should be a tuple or list of tensors. That means we cannot directly pass a scalar loss to it. (I don't know why, because I think there is no large difference between a scalar loss or a function that returns a scalar)
2. Second, I want to obtain a complete Hessian matrix, which is the second derivative of all parameters, and it should be in an appropriate order.

So here is the solution:

```
import torch
import numpy as np
from torch.nn import Module
import torch.nn.functional as F

class Net(Module):
    def __init__(self, h, w):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.c1 = torch.nn.Conv2d(1, 32, 3, 1, 1)
        self.f2 = torch.nn.Linear(32 * h * w, 5)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.c1(x)
        x = x.view(x.size(0), -1)
        x = self.f2(x)
        return x

def haha(a, b, c, d):
    p = [a.view(32, 1, 3, 3), b, c.view(5, 32 * 12 * 12), d]
    x = torch.randn(size=[8, 1, 12, 12], dtype=torch.float32)
    y = torch.randint(0, 5, [8])
    x = F.conv2d(x, p[0], p[1], 1, 1)
    x = x.view(x.size(0), -1)
    x = F.linear(x, p[2], p[3])
    loss = F.cross_entropy(x, y)
    return loss


if __name__ == '__main__':
    net = Net(12, 12)

    h = torch.autograd.functional.hessian(haha, tuple([_.view(-1) for _ in net.parameters()]))
    
    # Then we just need to fix tensors in h into a big matrix
```

I build a new function `haha` that works in the same way with the neural network `Net`. Notice that arguments `a, b, c, d` are all expanded into one-dimensional vectors, so that the shapes of tensors in `h` are all two dimensional, in good order and easy to be combined into a large hessian matrix.

In my example, the shapes of tensors in `h` is

```
# with relation to c1.weight and c1.weight, c1.bias, f2.weight, f2.bias
[288,288]
[288,32]
[288,23040]
[288,5]

# with relation to c2.bias and c1.weight, c1.bias, f2.weight, f2.bias
[32, 288]
[32, 32]
[32, 23040]
[32, 5]
...
```

So it is easy to see the meaning of the tensors and which part it is. All we need to do is to allocate a `(288+32+23040+5)*(288+32+23040+5)` matrix and fix the tensors in `h` into the corresponding locations.

I think the solution still could be improved, like we don't need to build a function works the same way with neural network, and transform the shape of parameters twice. But for now I don't have better ideas, if there is any better solution, please let me know.