# How to compute the Hessian of a large neural network in PyTorch?

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch, bert-language-model, transformer-model

How to compute the Hessian matrix of a large neural network or transformer model like BERT in PyTorch? I know `torch.autograd.functional.hessian`, but it seems like it only calculates the Hessian of a function, but not a neural network. I also saw the answer in [How to compute hessian matrix for all parameters in a network in pytorch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64024312/how-to-compute-hessian-matrix-for-all-parameters-in-a-network-in-pytorch). The problem is, I want to compute the Hessian with respect to the weights, but for large neural networks, it is very inefficient to write it as a function of the weights. Is there a better way to do this? Any suggestion is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Good question !

Answer (score 0):

After sometime I finally found a new feature in pytorch nightly build that solves this problem. The details are described in this comment: https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/49171#issuecomment-933814662. The solution uses the function `torch.autograd.functional.hessian` and the new feature `torch.nn.utils._stateless`. Notice that you have to install the nightly version of pytorch to use this new feature.

Comment: On what size of neural networks have you tried? Does the code crash when the model is too big?